# aws sagemaker - IAM permission to call get_role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

## Question

In which AWS documentation explains the IAM permissions required to run SageMaker in a SageMaker Studio?

## Problem

In a SageMaker Studio with an IAM policy [AmazonSageMakerFullAccess](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess) attached.

The AWS documentation [AmazonSageMakerFullAccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/security-iam-awsmanpol.html#security-iam-awsmanpol-AmazonSageMakerFullAccess):

> This policy grants administrative permissions that allow a principal full access to all Amazon SageMaker resources and operations. **The policy also provides select access to related services**.
>
> #### Permissions details
>
> This policy includes the following permissions.
> ... 
> iam – Needed to give the SageMaker console access to available IAM roles and create service-linked roles.

However, run the code below as instructed [SageMaker Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html) fails.

```
import sagemaker

sess = sagemaker.Session()
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
-----
Couldn't call 'get_role' to get Role ARN from role name <IAM Role Name> to get Role path.
```

[image]

## Fix

Attached `iam:GetRole` permission to solve the issue. However, where is it documented?

[image]

## Related

Apparently AWS acknowledged this is an issue in 2020 and has not updated document?

- [AWS SageMaker Github This project requires more permissions than AmazonSageMakerFullAccess gives it #2027](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/2027#issuecomment-765870062)

> Well yeah I found a solution, but you should probably fix the underlying problem- either in the documentation or in your policies themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your issue is resolved - and I tested it just now with only AmazonSageMakerFullAccess attached to my execution role, and I am able to execute the cell without any permission errors.

Edit: The [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/dev/README.rst#aws-permissions) is already updated to specify the permission required if your role has a path in it. If there is no path in your role, AmazonSageMakerFullAccess should suffice (as in my case).

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.